# QDoubleSpinBox: Stop emitting intermediate values

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I am subclassing QDoubleSpinBox to add some features (like incrementing the value based on the location of the cursor in the lineedit) and to change some features I find annoying. One of the latter is that intermediate values are emitted:  e.g. if you want to enter the value 323 it will emit 3 then 32 then finally 323.  I'd like to set it to only emit on entry (i.e. only actually change value on entry).

Anyway, I can't figure out how to capture these intermediate edits.  I overrode setValue to see if I could stop it there somehow, but it apparently isn't called (or at least my override isn't).  I'm not sure how the value is actually getting set while editing in line edit.

More generally, the logic of this box escapes me.  Is there some documentation that explains e.g. "if you type a digit into the lineedit then this series of routines is called... while if you hit the up arrow, this series of routines is called?"

In case it matters, I'm using PyQt5

EDIT:  Here is another case in which having access to this is important.  Say I want to implement an undo/redo structure for the box.  The only way I can think of to get access to the changed values is to connect to the valueChanged signal.  But if I'm subclassing the box it seems a little convoluted to listen for a signal rather than just watch the value change 'internally'  Or am I missing something here?

Comment: `setValue()` isn't a virtual function, so it's no surprising that it's not called when you override it

Comment: I'm not sure that there is anything 'wrong' with it, it is just isn't how I want the box to work.  Let's say I'm controlling an instrument that will have serious problems if a value sent to it is less than 10.  So I type in '20' and it gets sent 2 before it is sent 20. Yes, in this specific case I should do some checking on the instrument side, etc. but this is just a kind of situation where it isn't so convenient to emit intermediate values.

Comment: Don't use the `valueChanged` signal, use `editingFinished`. That signal is only emitted if the value was changed and the component looses focus, or when return is pressed.

Comment: "Is there some documentation that explains e.g. "if you type a digit into the lineedit then this series of routines is called... while if you hit the up arrow, this series of routines is called?"" This documentation is called the source code, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following signal:

```
void QAbstractSpinBox::editingFinished() [signal]
```

> This signal is emitted editing is finished. This happens when the spinbox loses focus and when enter is pressed.

based on the documentation of `QAbstractSpinBox`:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qabstractspinbox.html#editingFinished

There is nothing that combines the arrow based changes and the editingFinished changes.

Answer (score 2):

My use case was to let the user enter the value without getting the signal on each new digit, while still making <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys and arrow buttons work as usual, emitting the signal on each activation.

`QAbstractSpinBox::editingFinished` signal doesn't provide this functionality: it's only ever emitted when focus is lost or <kbd>Return</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

What does work exactly as I need is the [`keyboardTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking-prop) property of `QAbstractSpinBox`. If it's `true` (the default), the spinbox emits `valueChanged` on each digit typed. If you set it to `false`, it behaves exactly as I described in the beginning of this answer.